# 3D secure Credit Card of PayPal for Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have try PayPal link of [3D card](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/customize/3d-secure/test/) but it seems they didn't work. Is their any card which check 3D secure integeration on checkout in Magnento 2.

Comment: What is error? who did you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: HoangHieu It does not show error but also not show 3D secure window for SMS OTP verification and just complete the order.